# MongoDB $text search not returning expected results

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search

I created a text index based on `title` and `main_body` fields in my Mongo Collection. I have for instance an article with the title: "Abby Bengtsson" and her name "Abby", appearing throughout the actual article in `main_body`.

Making a text search query: `{$text: {$search: 'abby bengtsson'}}`, returns the desired article, along with a couple more.
[image]

But simply querying her first name: `{$text: {$search: 'abby'}}`, returns nothing.
[image]

I have tried using Mongo Compass, Downloaded Studio 3T, and using ssh and terminal commands on the server directly. 
[image]

But I don't understand why this happens.. The same goes for other key words in other articles.

### JSON Doc example

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e0f4ded35fbd16f21bf3655"), 
    "category" : {
        "category_id" : "5010", 
        "slug" : {
            "0010" : "profiler", 
            "0020" : "profiler", 
            "0030" : "profiler"
        }, 
        "label" : {
            "0010" : "Profiler", 
            "0020" : "Profiler", 
            "0030" : "Profiler"
        }, 
        "bg_color" : "#B12CA6", 
        "txt_color" : "#ffffff", 
        "main_category_id" : "5000"
    }, 
    "featured_image" : {
        "main" : "https://img.norrbom.com/article/5e0f4d5e35fbd16f21bf3653/78805a221a988e79ef3f42d7c5bfd418-1578061277668/abby.jpg", 
        "mobile" : "https://img.norrbom.com/article/5e0f4d5e35fbd16f21bf3653/78805a221a988e79ef3f42d7c5bfd418-1578061277668/abby.jpg", 
        "square" : "https://img.norrbom.com/article/5e0f4d5e35fbd16f21bf3653/78805a221a988e79ef3f42d7c5bfd418-1578061277668/abby.jpg"
    }, 
    "metadata" : {
        "title" : "Abby Bengtsson", 
        "description" : "Hon sprudlar av energi och glädje, vilket smittar av sig på hela redaktionen när hon kliver in hos En Sueco. Med sig har hon sin ursöta följeslagare pomeranianen Melwin", 
        "og" : {
            "title" : "Abby Bengtsson", 
            "description" : "Hon sprudlar av energi och glädje, vilket smittar av sig på hela redaktionen när hon kliver in hos En Sueco. Med sig har hon sin ursöta följeslagare pomeranianen Melwin", 
            "image" : "https://img.norrbom.com/article/5e0f4d5e35fbd16f21bf3653/78805a221a988e79ef3f42d7c5bfd418-1578061277668/abby.jpg", 
            "type" : "article", 
            "site_name" : "En Sueco", 
            "url" : "https://www.ensueco.com/profil-abby-bengtsson"
        }, 
        "twitter" : {
            "title" : "Abby Bengtsson", 
            "description" : "Hon sprudlar av energi och glädje, vilket smittar av sig på hela redaktionen när hon kliver in hos En Sueco. Med sig har hon sin ursöta följeslagare pomeranianen Melwin", 
            "card" : "summary", 
            "image" : "https://img.norrbom.com/article/5e0f4d5e35fbd16f21bf3653/78805a221a988e79ef3f42d7c5bfd418-1578061277668/abby.jpg"
        }
    }, 
    "tags" : [

    ], 
    "title" : "Abby Bengtsson", 
    "state" : NumberInt(1), 
    "created" : ISODate("2020-01-01T04:17:00.000+0000"), 
    "modified" : ISODate("2020-01-01T08:27:54.000+0000"), 
    "version" : NumberInt(19), 
    "featured" : false, 
    "language" : "sv", 
    "magazines" : [

    ], 
    "slug" : "profil-abby-bengtsson", 
    "published" : ISODate("2020-01-02T10:14:00.000+0000"), 
    "published_until" : null, 
    "author_alias" : "Text: Sara Laine, sara@norrbom.com Foto: Mugge Fischer, mugge@norrbom.com", 
    "main_body" : "... stringified JSON object with article ...", 
    "article_id" : ObjectId("5e0f4d5e35fbd16f21bf3653"), 
    "origin" : "cms", 
    "site" : "0020", 
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

## EDIT 18-01-2020

I just tested something. It seems, that this issue only occurs for documents where the `language` property is set to `sv` (Swedish as per [MongoDB Language Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages)). If I change the value to `da` (Danish), the document is being returned, when I search for "Abby".

I have currently solved my issue in production, by setting `language_overwrite` to a dummy field that doesn't exist.. Now all fields are being returned as they should. But the thing with the swedish language field still confuses me, as it is ONLY when I se the field to "sv" - and what sense does it make to have multiple language documents, and a text index that supposedly should return and search based on locale, if it doesn't work for one particular language variable?

Comment: Try this { $text: {$search: 'abby', $caseSensitive: false}}

Comment: How did you create the text index? Can you show add the script? Also a few sample documents in json format would be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of MongoDB are you using?  The functionality has changed a bit version to version.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#versions for more details.

I tested this out in 4.2 and got the results you would expect.

To test this out I created a free cluster in Atlas (cloud.mongodb.com) and loaded the sample data.  Then I navigated to the Collections tab.  The sample data contains a database named "sample_mflix" with a collection called "movies".  My collection had a default text index that covered the following fields: cast_text_fullplot_text_genres_text_title_text.

Then I navigated to the Find tab. When I ran the searches you described, I got the results you would expect. Both {$text: {$search: 'abby bengtsson'}} and {$text: {$search: 'abby'}} return many results

**Update based on new information added to original question on 18-01-20**

I spoke with a colleague who explained to me what is going on:

It is worth noting that text search is designed for stemming with language heuristics. This will have unexpected outcomes with proper nouns like "Abby" (and with multi-language search).

Using query explain output for insight, this is what is happening:
- Abby stems to abby in Swedish but abbi in English, so the term is indexed as abby given the language value of sv in the document.
- A search without any language will default to English (rather than trying to stem in all possible languages) so a default search will not match the indexed term.

To search matching the indexed language they would have to provide a language value, eg: db.articles.find({$text: {$search: 'abby', $language: 'sv'}}).

This is working as designed but doesn't match the user's expectation that queries would be stemmed to match all possible languages (which is probably an unhelpful outcome in terms of relevance).

What they actually want is the solution they arrived at: they should index with a language of none for simple tokenisation without stemming or stopwords.

Comment: AHHHHHH!!!!!!! I have read the documentation wrong.. Thanks a lot.. Something so silly...